# Lock doesn't lock in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, locking

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, current_process
import requests as r

def get(lista, lista_lock):
    lista_lock.acquire()
    print(f"PID: {current_process().name} ID liste: {id(lista)}")
    temp = lista[:1]
    del lista[:1]
    lista_lock.release()
    res = r.get(*temp)
    print(f"PID: {current_process().name} ->  {res.url}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lista = ["https://www.index.hr", "https://www.24sata.hr"]

    lista_lock = Lock() 

    p1 = Process(target=get, args=(lista, lista_lock))
    p2 = Process(target=get, args=(lista, lista_lock))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print(f"lista ID: {id(lista)}")
```

What I get as a result is...

```
PID: Process-1 ID liste: 140292127163144
PID: Process-2 ID liste: 140292127163144
PID: Process-1 ->  https://www.index.hr/
PID: Process-2 ->  https://www.index.hr/
lista ID: 140292127163144
```

Each process should have gotten different links, but they fetched the same. Lock doesn't seem to work. Can someone please help me.

I have 1 more question regarding the ID of "lista". If these are different processes why do the have the same variable "lista"? I thought each process gets their own copy of data.

Comment: This isn't shared memory - the list has to be copied to each process, and each process gets a separate copy.

Comment: ID distinctness guarantees don't apply to objects in different processes.

Comment: FYI, `del lista[:1]` is better written as `del lista[0]`

Comment: Use threads if you want to share the objects.

Comment: Multiprocessing works by pickling objects to disk and then the child processes loading that data. Once the process is up and running, there is no more data sharing unless you implement some kind of IPC.

Comment: This is running on linux?

Comment: @jordanm - Spawned processes (windows) use pickle, but not to disk. It can just be passed in an interprocess channel. Forked processes (linux) don't copy the data at all.

Comment: @tdelaney yes it's running on Linux

Comment: @tdelaney for linux not pickling, is that a 3.x change? I know I have encountered pickle errors on linux using multiprocessing before, but it was years ago in the 2.x days.

Comment: @jordanm - multiprocessing does some pickling for the stuff that is passed on queues in both windows and linux, so I think I  overstated things a bit!

Answer (score 1):

On unix-like systems, `Process` will fork a subprocess with a copy-on-write view of the parent memory space. On Windows, it will spawn a new python process and will attempt to pickle/unpickle relevant state to the child. In both cases, the child gets the full `lista` and any popping or deleting items is only valid for that subprocess. (In your case, your code won't work on Windows because locks can't be pickled).

You could use a `multiprocessing.Manager` to creates views of the list that are proxied in the two processes but that is usually not very efficient. Use `Pool` instead, its already built for what you want.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import requests as r

def get(item):
    print(f"PID: {mp.current_process().name} item: {item}")
    res = r.get(item)
    print(f"PID: {mp.current_process().name} ->  {res.url}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lista = ["https://www.index.hr", "https://www.24sata.hr"]

    pool = mp.Pool(min(len(lista), mp.cpu_count())) 
    pool.map(get, lista)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: this running on Linux